# Different types of Android Intents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have recently started a new Android project and I'm working off the previous developer's code. I'm relatively new to Android and I've come across something that I'm unsure of.

What is the difference between this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.project.MENU");
```

and this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMenu.class);
```

I understand what the 2nd code snippet does, I just can't get my head around as to what the first one is doing? Is it referencing the file in the package? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is an **implicit** intent, while the second is an **explicit** intent.

The first one fired an `Intent` for the **action** com.example.project.MENU. If you look inside you project `AndroidManifest.xml` you can see some `<intent-filter>` balise. This baslise register activity, service or broadcast receiver to different actions.

This mecanism can be used to allow third party app to launch some of your activities.

You can see more on this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html#intenttypes

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks very much! I found the links to the new activities in the manifest.

Answer (score 2):

Basically an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) carries some information that are used by the system in order to determine which component should be called for executing the action.

These information are:

- **Component name**: the name of the component that should be launched. (If present the Intent is Explicit)
- **Action**: it specifies the generic action that should be executed (es. `ACTION_VIEW`, `ACTION_SEND`). It determines how the rest of the intent is strucutred.
- **Data**: represents the URI that refers to the object that should be associated with the action. For example with the action `ACTION_EDIT`, the Data should contain the URI of the document that you want modify.
- **Category**: Additional infromation (for example if you want that your app is shown in the launcher you can use `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`)
- **Extras**: keys-values pairs that carries additional information
- **Flags**: it is like a metadata that specify how the intent should be managed by the system.

The `Intent` class provides a lot of different constructors.

The first one you asked for is [`public Intent (String action)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(java.lang.String))

So, this sets the `Action`, and lets null all other fields.

The second one [`public Intent (Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E)) creates an intent for a specific component by its `Component name`. All other fields are null. This is a Explicit Intent, since you declare exactly which component should receive it.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is used when you need to call Intent from System

such as Open Camera, Gallery, or Share something to other Application

for example

```
// this one call Camera to Capture Image
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

// this one call gallery to let you select image
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

and That MediaStore.something here is just a Path to the system

for example

> MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE = "android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"
>
> Intent.ACTION_PICK = "android.intent.action.PICK"

Answer (score 0):

The first type of intent is mostly used if you want to open another application from your application while the second type of intent is used to open another activity in your application.